# Identifying specific changes via audit table

Tags: sql, audit

I have an audit table in a SQL database that is structured like the one below:

| audit_id | id | location | location_sub | location_status | dtm_utc_action | action_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2144 | 2105 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 2022-09-08 12:36 | i |
| 4653 | 2105 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 2022-09-08 13:53 | u |
| 7304 | 2105 | 10 | 2 | 2 | 2022-09-13 15:51 | u |
| 7326 | 2105 | 11 | 1 | 2 | 2022-09-14 10:06 | u |

I'm trying to write a query that will assist me in finding records from this table where the location has changed, and would like to show the ID, old location, new location and time of the change.

Based on some other questions, I've tried joining the table with itself, but I don't understand how to prevent duplication. This query below will return each record multiple times, which isn't desired.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.location       AS old_loc, 
    a.dtm_utc_action AS FirstModifyDate,
    b.location       AS new_loc, 
    b.dtm_utc_action AS SecondModifyDate  

FROM
    audit_table a
    JOIN audit_table b ON a.id = b.id

WHERE
    a.audit_id <> b.audit_id
    AND
    a.dtm_utc_action < b.dtm_utc_action
    AND
    a.location <> b.location
    AND
    a.id = '2105'
```

Would like results to look like this:

| id | old_loc | new_loc | dtm_utc_action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2105 | 9 | 10 | 2022-09-13 15:50 |
| 2105 | 10 | 11 | 2022-09-14 10:06 |

Comment: Why is the column called `id` if it is not a row identifier? What is the table's actual PK?

Comment: Have you tried `a.audit_id < b.audit_id` ?

Comment: @Dai the PK is audit_id, id is the PK from the table this audit table is logging changes from - I renamed it for this, but I can see how that is confusing. It's an inventory identifier, so as the inventory moves that location will change, but audit_id is unique in this audit table.

Comment: @Simeon yes, but I will see see that first row with location of 9 matched with both the location of 10 and location 11, so it doesn't prevent that and I only want to show the 9 to 10, then 10 to 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS you can use a `LEAD` function to retrieve the next date from the audit table

```
with audit_sequence as (
    select *, lead(dtm_utc_action) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dtm_utc_action) next_update
    from audit_table 
) 

SELECT
    a.id,
    a.location       AS old_loc, 
    a.dtm_utc_action AS FirstModifyDate,
    b.location       AS new_loc, 
    b.dtm_utc_action AS SecondModifyDate  

FROM
    audit_table a
    JOIN audit_sequence s on a.id = s.id and a.dtm_utc_action = s.dtm_utc_action
    JOIN audit_table b on a.id = b.id and b.dtm_utc_action = s.next_update
WHERE
    a.location <> b.location
    AND
    a.id = '2105'
```